# How to start a variable as None and overwrite with float

Tags: python, nonetype

I have following variables:

```
A, B = None, None
```

I need to overwrite above variables with float as below:

```
for i in range(5):
       A += float(i)
       B *= float(i)
```

But i get below error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Comment: Why not start with `0.0`?

Comment: Start with `0, 1` ?

Comment: so use something hacky and bad way like `A = (A or 0) + i`

Comment: "not supposed to overwrite them"—But your question specifically says you *do* want to overwrite them.

Comment: because I am working on an assignment where variables are initialized for me as above and I am supposed to overwrite them.

Specific instructions are:
# initialize variables that student code should overwrite

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's the initializers you should "overwrite". (That is, the "overwrite" does not refer to later assignments to the variables.)

Comment: If you are supposed to overwrite then it doesn't matter if you use 0,1

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add and multiply a None value (+/*). If you just want to override use:

```
A = float(i)
B = float(i)
```

If you want to perform the operation (+/*) initialize to 0 and 1:

```
A , B = 0, 1
```